# Can I add an additional computed property to an Ember ArrayProxy?

Tags: arrays, ember.js, model, controller

I'm working on a legacy Ember app that has a bit of a funky setup and I'm trying to clean things up and follow conventions a bit more.  One issue is that, rather than returning an array from the `model` hook of an index route, we're returning an object that contains an array. So, I'm wrapping the `model` in an `ArrayProxy` in `setupController` like this:

```
setupController: (controller, model) ->
  model_proxy = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: model.get('item')})
  controller.set('content', model_proxy)
```

This actually works (i.e. `content` is updated when the AJAX promise resolves and `model.item` is loaded with data). The problem is, there's another property on `model` that I also need in my controller. `model` has a `needsLoader` property which is initialized to true and then set to false when the promise resolves. We're using this to show a spinner to the user while the data is being fetched from the server.

So, my question is: is there any way that I can proxy `needsLoader` in the `ArrayProxy`?

One solution I have tried is to hook the original `model` onto the controller in a non-standard way:

```
setupController: (controller, model) ->
  ....
  controller.set('_model', model)
  ....
```

This lets me access `needsLoader` from the controller by calling `@get('_model.needsLoader')`. It works, but I'd like to do all of the dirty work in the Router so that I have a clean interface in my controller to just call `model` as usual.

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you to use the 'model' hook, why aren't you using it ?, if you use it, you will have all the features provided by the router api, like this one http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-loading-code-event, if you check the comments in the code, you can place the spinner there. And you could also define it in the ApplicationRoute, that way, the spinner will show for all models being loaded.

Comment: This is just a simple example of one piece of data hanging off of the array. We're using hal so there is a lot of meta-data that I need to handle in a similar manner.

Comment: so, basically, you're setting the needsLoader once all that metadata has been loaded ? is that what you mean ? because you can do that with promises in your model.

Comment: I am setting the flag with promises in _my_ model. I want to access the meta-data from the controller with a call like `@get('model.needsLoader')`. To do that, I need the meta-data on `model_proxy`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it makes sense, but you can create your own type:

```
var myArrayProxy = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
  countPlusTen: function(){
    return this.get('content.length') + 10;
  }.property('content.length')
});


var instance = myArrayProxy.create({
  content: [1,2,3]
});

console.log(instance.get('countPlusTen'));
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/novavuqi/1/edit

Comment: That's not quite what I need to do. This would work for computing properties off of the ArrayProxy's `content` but I need data from the original model that the ArrayProxy doesn't know anything about. I keep going back and forth between extending ArrayProxy and using the Array Mixin.

Comment: Would you mind showing an example of what you'd like, you can use emberjs.jsbin.com as a template.

Comment: I actually just figured this out. I wound up using the MutableArray Mixin and lifting a lot of code from ArrayProxy. I'll post up a better answer once I'm done testing.