# Filtering Ember ArrayProxy

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How would you filter the result of an ArrayProxy? I've tried slice, filter, rejectBy, all leading to no result in the view. I imagine it's because the data isn't available yet, but usage of then(...) hasn't panned out either. Any thoughts?

```
shownEvents: function(){
    return Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Em.SortableMixin, {
        content: this.get('shownUser.events'),
        sortProperties: ['eventTime.startTime', 'eventTime.endTime'],
        sortAscending: true
    });
  }.property("shownUser"),
```

I've reviewed quite a few articles similar to this but haven't found anything that quite works.

[Can I add an additional computed property to an Ember ArrayProxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318151/can-i-add-an-additional-computed-property-to-an-ember-arrayproxy)

Comment: can you replicate this in jsbin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter `ArrayProxy` by passing in a function to `filter` and returning `true` for the values that should pass the filtering test.

Something like:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return { pets: [ { type: 'dog'}, { type: 'cat'}, { type: 'fish'}] };
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  myPets: function(){
    return Em.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Em.SortableMixin, {
      content: this.get('pets'),
      sortProperties: ['type'],
      sortAscending: true
    }).filter(function(item){ return item.type.length === 3});
  }.property("pets"),
});
```

Works [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/faluci/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Fill free to ignore this if you have tried this already ;)

Comment: Thanks @Kalman Hazins ; I had tried but I think there is a slight delay because of the delay/promise with async. Sideloaded this works perfectly, async/promise hasn't yet panned out. That said, I didn't really specify that in the OP, so this is definitely the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: But..., this .filter(...)..., will it return another instance of ArrayProxy? And if yes, will the 'arrangedContent' of this new instance contains only the items that passed the filter?